# How to find difference between two lists in coq

Tags: coq

**I have two lists in coq.I want to find the difference between these two lists.Plz guide me in writing code in coq**

Comment: What do you mean by "difference between two lists"?

Comment: I have few natural numbers in one list,some other natural  number in other list.I want to find natural number common  in both lists.Difference will be zero ,if no common element exist between them.

Answer (score 0):

As Arthur says there are many versions of difference. If you mean subtraction here are two approaches:

```
Variable (T: eqType).

Definition dlist1 (l1 l2 : seq T) :=
  foldr (fun x l => if x \in l2 then l else [:: x & l]) [::] l1.

Definition dlist2 (l1 l2 : seq T) :=
  foldl (fun l x => filter (predC1 x) l) l1 l2.
```

YMMV. Proofs:

```
Lemma dlist2_nil l2 : dlist2 [::] l2 = [::].
Proof. by elim: l2. Qed.

Lemma dlist2_cons x1 l1 l2 :
  dlist2 (x1 :: l1) l2 =
  if x1 \in l2 then dlist2 l1 l2 else [:: x1 & dlist2 l1 l2].
Proof. by elim: l2 l1 => //= x2 l2 ih2 l1; rewrite inE; case: eqP => /=. Qed.

Lemma dlistP l1 l2 : dlist1 l1 l2 = dlist2 l1 l2.
Proof.
by elim: l1 l2 => [|x1 l1 ih1] /= l2; rewrite ?dlist2_nil // dlist2_cons ih1.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is not the difference between the two lists, but their intersection.  You can program this function by reusing parts of the standard library.

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.

Definition intersection (l1 l2 : list nat) : list nat :=
  List.filter (fun n => List.existsb (Nat.eqb n) l2) l1.

Lemma intersectionP l1 l2 n : In n (intersection l1 l2) <-> In n l1 /\ In n l2.
Proof.
unfold intersection.
rewrite filter_In, existsb_exists; split.
- intros [H1 [m [H2 e]]]; split; trivial.
  rewrite Nat.eqb_eq in e; congruence.
- intros [H1 H2]; split; trivial.
  now exists n; split; trivial; rewrite Nat.eqb_refl.
Qed.
```